# AngularJS Full-Stack generator not saving js or controller to index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, generator

I have appreciated the Yeoman approach to development, and recently began using [generator-angular-fullstack](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-fullstack).

I tried to create a route, using:

`yo angular-fullstack:route myroute`

The documentation says it will wire up all the boilerplate, which the generator did, BUT, strangely it didn't include the javascript or controller for the new route into a  tag within the index.html file, and I had to manually include this tags.

Isn't the point of the generator to cut down on the repetitious boilerplate?  The plain-jane Yeoman Angular generator does so.

I'm I missing something here?  Is there a --save type flag?  Pretty great tool otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

You should end up with - I think I'm on v2.0.13

```
<script src="app/work/myroute.controller.js"></script>
<script src="app/work/myroute.js"></script>
```

just below main.js.  If not maybe you have a permissions issue?

Also make sure you are up to date they move pretty fast.

```
npm update -g yo   
npm update -g generator-angular-fullstack
```

Also I would just try to generate a new project and see if it works any different because the whole directory structure changed recently.

Comment: I'm on v2.0.13, with requirements greater in version than expected. Not sure what to do:

`$ npm list -g generator-angular-fullstack
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-package-data requires github-url-from-git@'~1.1.1' but will load /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/github-url-from-git, which is version 1.4.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-package-data requires github-url-from-username-repo@'^0.2.0' but will load
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/github-url-from-username-repo,which is version 1.0.0`